# div disappears without waiting for onclick event - HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please could anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? I am just trying to make the green div disappear when I click on it by passing its Id as an argument to the 'disappear' function. However, the div is already gone when the html loads in the browser.

Thank you!!!

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Javascript challenge</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style type="text/css">

    #cuadrado {

        width:200px;

        height:200px;

        background-color:green;

        display:block;

        }

</style>

</head>


<body>

    <div id="cuadrado">

    </div>


    <!-------------------- SCRIPT -------------------------------->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function disappear(x)

            {

            document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";

            }

        document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = disappear("cuadrado");

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `disappear("cuadrado")` which is actually invoking the function and is passing the value returned by it(`undefined`) as the onclick handler.

You need to set a function reference to onclick

```
function disappear(x) {
    document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = function () {
    disappear("cuadrado")
};
```

```js
function disappear(x) {
  document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = function() {
  disappear("cuadrado")
};
```

```css
#cuadrado {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuadrado">

</div>
```

another solution is to use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) like

```
document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = disappear.bind(window, "cuadrado")
```

```js
function disappear(x) {
  document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = disappear.bind(window, "cuadrado")
```

```css
#cuadrado {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuadrado"></div>
```

Or in your case since you want to hide the clicked element itself

```
function disappear() {
    this.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = disappear;
```

```js
function disappear() {
  this.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("cuadrado").onclick = disappear;
```

```css
#cuadrado {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuadrado"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Arun! I thought "function()" could be replaced by the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case as alternative you can try adding `click` as `eventlistner` as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dqycu140/1/)**

```
document.getElementById("cuadrado").addEventListener("click", function(){
     disappear(this.id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

reference link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_addeventlistener

```js
  document.getElementById("cuadrado").addEventListener("click", disappear);
        function disappear()

            {

            document.getElementById("cuadrado").style.display = "none";

            }
```

```css
   #cuadrado {

        width:200px;

        height:200px;

        background-color:green;

        display:block;

        }
```

```html
<div id="cuadrado">

    </div>
```

also try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var div =   document.getElementById("cuadrado");
 div.addEventListener('click', function (event) {    
     disappear("cuadrado")
 });
    function disappear(x)

        {

        document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";

        }



</script>
```